# Understanding the side effects of localdatastore in parse.com API

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am making an app that will let user keep notes - simple text entries. I want to persist these to the backend and `Parse.com` seems to make it easy. While going over their documentation, I came across this:

> There are a couple of side effects of enabling the local datastore
>   that you should be aware of. When enabled, there will only be one
>   instance of any given ParseObject. For example, imagine you have an
>   instance of the "GameScore" class with an objectId of "xWMyZ4YEGZ",
>   and then you issue a ParseQuery for all instances of "GameScore" with
>   that objectId. The result will be the same instance of the object you
>   already have in memory.

Say that my class is called `NoteEntry`. Since the user will create a number of notes, there will be a lot of `NoteEntry`s. **Does the side effect mean that only a single `NoteEntry` can ever exist in the database?**

and

> Another side effect is that the current user and current installation
>   will be stored in the local datastore, so you can persist unsaved
>   changes to these objects between runs of your app using the methods
>   below.

I don't even know what that means. **What is it saying?**

Doc: https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#localdatastore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not the side effect.  You can still be dealing with lots of Parse objects, it just means that there will be only one copy of each different object.  If you had a NoteEntry object in variable `x` and later query and that same object is returned, it will be equal to the object in `x` and not a separate copy of the object.

Comment: Basically, it is saying that it will avoid redundancy. No duplicate data. Cool. What is the second part saying? :) Is it related to `ParseUser` object?

Comment: if you make changes to the current logged in user on the device, and don't explicitly save them to Parse, they will be persisted in local storage and you could save them later.

Comment: It is related to the Google account with which the user is logged into the device or the account with which the user has logged into Parse? Sorry if my questions are basic, I am a novice :)

Comment: the parse user account (if logged in) and the installation object (if push notifications enabled)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks a lot! One last question. Doc says the `saveEventually` will keep the data pinned until it is uploaded to the backend and then unpin. What if I want it to stay pinned? :) Doc hasn't mentioned that anywhere

Comment: Then explicitly .pin it.

Comment: Cool. `pin()` and then `saveEnevtually()` :) I *thought* it will unpin it as soon as the saving is done. Can't thank you enough for your help :)